# android system milli second convertion

Tags: android, time, system

I have a time of Hour and minute. 
like 21:30 and 21:35
i want to start an stopwatch which will start at 21:30 and stop at 21:35

From searching the net i find it necessarily done by checking  `SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()` to stored second in a thread. 
but i have just hour and minute and how i convert in  SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), because  SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() comes from full time data.

I dont need code, but just want to have a good suggestion about logic that should do it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using the Calendar class and extract the hour and min from it.

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```